# Cant use **!** for pip install in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to use `! git clone` to clone a repository into a specific directory.

But I noticed I can't use ! at all in my Jupyter Lab. The code runs with no error but nothing gets printed out. I double confirmed this using `!pip list`.

The actual code I am trying to run is

```
LABELIMG_PATH = os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'labelimg')

if not os.path.exists(LABELIMG_PATH):
    os.makedirs(LABELIMG_PATH)
    ! git clone https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg {LABELIMG_PATH}
```

But it runs instantly creating the labelimg folder without running the git clone code.

for `!pip list` it also runs instantly without printing any packages in the output cell.

I have checked and the virtual environment is being used in the kernel, I thought it was because of ipykernel packages and installed the few lines of code below.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pywin32
conda install -c anaconda jupyter_client
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_core
```

But after rebooting it still didn't work. I checked other virtual environments and `! pip list` also didnt work.

I also tried `! pip3 list`, `!pip list`, `!pip3 list` and it all didn't work.

Would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

EDIT:

line 10 is the code I wish to use to clone the repo, line 13 is the next line which I have not run kindly ignore, the purpose was to show the output of line 10, as you can see it runs successfully almost instantly with no output
[image: Outoput for running Repo.clone]

But the folder is empty and nothing is cloned.

Comment: The `!` prefix commands are special and can't be mixed with python code like that

Comment: @lejohntanjunyen : What is the `!`  supposed to do in Python code? And why is this question labelled _shell_?

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong and it can, but there mustn't be a space after the `!` so it should be `!pip list`

Comment: @lejohntanjunyen : I just found that `!` has special meaning for an interactive jupyter command; however you seem to use it inside normal Python code.

Comment: @user1934428 - The `!` is Jupyter magic to run a shell command

Comment: @user1934428 what i understood with `!pip` was it is a shell command, did I understand it wrongly?

Comment: @user1934428 shouldn't it work in Jupyter if it's a Jupyter magic to run shell commands? I used to be able to run `!pip3 install package` but currently no shell command can be run with `!`

Comment: @JiříBaum I did `!pip list` as well but it didnt work, is Jupyter magic a package I have to install before using? I cant seem to find it in Google mentioning I have to install it

Comment: No, line magic should just work, or at least give an error message

Comment: Alright, I will restart my computer and and try it again, will update you tomorrow ! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to run pip install of any sort you need not add a "!"

You just directly run pip install
"!" prefix commands as mentioned are special to be used in a particular code block with git and other similar commands. 
If you want to clone the repo from your python code, use the library -> GitPython

```
from git import Repo
Repo.clone_from("git path here", "directory to clone to")
```

Comment: I have tried 
`Repo.clone_from("https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg", LABELIMG_PATH)`
`Repo.clone_from("https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg", "labelimg")` , both which did not work, they both run instantly successfully but nothing was cloned into the folder (labelimg)

Comment: but i did try `pip list` and it printed out `Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.`, so i restarted the kernel and run cells up to `pip list` and close Jupyter + the Powershell and rerun everything, but it still prints out the same output `Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.`

Comment: It's working for me.... I wonder why it isn't for you.... When you run it do you get output as: <git.Repo "D:\new_folder\.git">... If possible share an ss of what comes up when you run Repo.clone_from

Comment: @FrankyPinto - The `!` syntax is Jupyter-specific; see https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access

Comment: @JiříBaum yess,I know... Not only for jupyter... Any notebook based interfaces like Collab, Kaggle, etc use ! for special commands... I gave a solution for if the need is to run the git clone from a python code

Comment: @FrankyPinto I have shared the image in the original text under EDIT, as i cant seem to share images in the comment section here

Comment: so in the end i used the terminal to manually select the directory and used `git clone https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg` to clone the repository, i cant seem to make `Repo.clone_home` work do let me know if its not something i should do, as you can tell Im still new to this, thanks once again everyone !

Comment: Can you run Repo.clone_from() in another code block after code block 10, like in code block 11, then run both one after the other?